# How to check if function is a probability function?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

### Background

I'm trying to grasp exercise 1.1 from chapter 2 in Allan Guts "An intermediate course in pobability". In this question:

Start with a 2-dimensional discrete random variable $(X,Y)$

Define the conditional probability function $p_{Y|X=x}(y)=p_{X,Y}(x,y)/p_X(x)$

Use the definition of the marginal $p_X(x)=\sum_y p_{X,Y}(x,y)$

We are asked to verify that $p_{Y|X=x}(y)$ indeed "is a probability function of a true probability distribution."

In the presentation by Gut, there is no properties that qualifies such functions, he only gives definitions on what a probability function is, in relation to the underlying probability space. Naïvely I feel I must go back and specify from the probability space all the way up to the probability function.

### Question

Inspired by some previous answers on math SE (but these are continous pdf's over $\mathbb R$), I'm inclined to only check that

1. Total probability is 1, i.e. $\sum_{y}p_{Y|X=x}(y) = 1$
2. The probability function is non-negative, i.e. $p_{Y|X=x}(y)\geq 0 , \forall y$.

Would these two conditions suffice in Alan Guts exercise above?

If they do - why dont we have to respecify the whole probability measure and so on?

If they don't - what is the proper criteria to check?

Comment: Presumably you know each $p_{X,Y}^{\,}(x,y) \ge 0$ and that $\sum\limits_{x,y}p_{X,Y}^{\,}(x,y) =1$.  You may also need $p_{X}^{\,}(x) =\sum\limits_{y}p_{X,Y}^{\,}(x,y) \gt 0$ for all $x$ in the support of $p_{X,Y}^{\,}$

Comment: It is enough. Provided of course that $p_{Y\mid X=x}(y)$ is well defined (i.e. $p_X(x)>0$). It proves that you are dealing with a PMF and nothing more is asked from you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this answer I will try to explain why it is enough to check 1) and 2).

**Lemma**:

If $S$ is a countable set and $p:S\to\mathbb R$ is a nonnegative function that satisfies $\sum_{s\in S}p(s)=1$ then the function $P:\wp(S)\to\mathbb R$ prescribed by: $$A\mapsto\sum_{s\in A}p(s)$$is a probability measure.

---

It is a good thing to (try to) prove that yourself, but if you have done that **for once** then *you do not have to repeat it anymore for special cases*.

That's why it is enough just to check 1) and 2). For the other conditions you just tacitly use the lemma.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so $Y$ does appear to be a discrete random variables, then you do need check:

1. Total probability is 1, that is $\sum_{y}p_{\small Y\mid X=x}(y) = 1\quad, \forall x$ .
2. The probability function is non-negative, i.e. $p_{\small Y\mid X=x}(y)\geq 0 \quad, \forall y,\forall x$.

Also, although it is a consequence of the above, it is usual to check that:

3. A probability *mass* function is at most one. $p_{\small Y\mid X=x}(y)\leq 1 \quad, \forall y,\forall x$.

Comment: 3 is a consequence of 1 and 2

Comment: Indeed...……....

Comment: the typo has now been fixed. sorry about that.

Comment: why does it suffice with these two checks? they look like kolmogorov axioms 1 and 2, but why dont we check kolmogorov axiom 3 too?

Comment: If all probability masses are non-negative, and their sum equals one, none of them may exceed one. @LudvigH  But, although it is redundant, it is still good practice to check.